# Intellij idea cannot find gdx-archetype

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm trying to create a libgdx project. I first followed the instructions in https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-maven-archetype, and clicked the "add archetype" in the idea to add the libgdx; however, when the progress finished, it occurred:

```
[WARNING] No archetype found in remote catalog. Defaulting to internal catalog
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository.
[WARNING] Add a repository with id 'archetype' in your settings.xml if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
[WARNING] Property JavaGameClassName is missing. Add -DJavaGameClassName=someValue
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:22 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-14T23:53:19+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/363M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Archetype com.badlogic.gdx:gdx-archetype:1.2.0 is not configured
[ERROR] Property JavaGameClassName is missing.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

But if I use the command line to create a project manually, it could finish successfully. Why could it happen?